# Can I use titanium to build a web app and mobile apps?

Tags: android, titanium

Are you able to use titanium to build a mobile web app, such that it can run on something like m.website.com and also have a mobile version of the app packaged to Android or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you cannot.

titanium is complied code that needs to be deployed on a mobile device.

you are looking for something like [phoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com)

Answer (score 1):

Now, the answer is Yes.
Since Titanium 2.X you can also deploy your stuff as a mobile web project,
see http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Mobile_Web_Support :

> "Titanium Mobile SDK version 2.0 or newer is recommended for Mobile Web development."

At the moment Titanium 3.X deals with following platforms:

- Android
- Blackberry
- iOS
- Tizen (a free Linux-based mobile OS)
- Mobile Web

see http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-MobileDevelopment

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot do.

But you can do the mobile web